# delete all sub-directories recursively except several ones

Tags: command-line, rm

The main_directory includes 0001 0102 0203 ... sub-directories.
The sub-directories include lots of directories.  I need to delete all sub-directories except several ones whose names are "abc", "bcd" and "123", for example.

How can do this deleting processing using command?

Comment: to be clear are you looking to avoid deleting all the folders with those names no matter how deep they are in the file system? or are you just interested in saving the ones that are one layer deep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Quick and dirty, but very efficient:

```
shopt extglob   # possibly already there
shopt globstar  # not often the default
rmdir ./**/!(abc|def) # rinse and repeat
```

In slo-mo:

- `extglob` enables bash extended patterns (including tings like `!(abc|def)` that means (anything but `abc`or`def`)
- `globstar` makes `**` match any level of directories
- so `./**/!(abc|def)` will match everything not called `abc` or `def` (I am assuming you have removed the files already, otherwise with a slightly different pattern you can `rm` the files too [*] )
- since the directories are listed top-down, the `rmdir` for the top levels will come before the lower levels are removed, which is why you may have to repeat the command a few times.

#### More classical with `find`

You can also use `find` (with `-depth` to process subdirectories first):

```
find . -depth -type d \( \! -name 'abc' -a \! -name 'def' \) -exec rmdir {} \;
```

but as you see the command will be rather verbose if you have more than a couple of directories to ignore.

[*] `rm ./**/!(abc|def)/*.txt` for instance

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is to use `find`

I believe this command will do what you want.

```
find /path/to/dir/ -not -path "*/abc*" -not -path "*/bcd*" -not -path "*/123*" -type f -delete
```

But I would suggest running it without the `-delete` or the `type f -delete` first so that you can see what is being removed. Or even run it on a test set of directories to make sure it's doing what you think it is before running it on your important files.

For more information about this and other methods on how to do this using `find` see the following question 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87258/delete-all-files-except-in-a-certain-subdirectory-with-find

**Edit:**

To clear up some confusion about the use of `-type f` instead of `-type d` , if you try it you will see that it actually does what OP is asking. The `-type d` flag actually results in the order of the files and directories being listed in a different order. As such the `delete` tries to remove the directory before the file in the directory have been removed (which it is not allowed to do). So to use the `-type d` flag the order of the listed files would have to be reversed which is possible but also seemed like an unneeded step as the `type -f` flag actually works deleting both files and directories.